# How to make php more secure in unity

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I wish to update a table in a database using php. I'm developing a game in unity using php to retrieve and update data. Each user logs in with their FB details (the correct way by using the FB API), but for now the username is a unique int ID and a **sc** column that needs to be updated.

Here is a link example: http://www.mydomain.co.za/php/myphp2.php?id=1&sc="1,2"

#### PHP code (myphp2.php):

```
<?php

require_once('/home/########/public_html/php/mysqli_connect.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$selected_cards = $_GET['sc'];

$query = "UPDATE PlayerCards SET SelectedCards=$selected_cards WHERE ID=$id";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($response){
    echo 'Updated the sc of the selected id';

} else {
    echo 'could not execute database query 2';
}
?>
```

This way I can update any user's **sc** value using a browser. (BIG PROBLEM)

Here is my C# scripts for Unity that retrieves the facebook user's login ID that I will use in my database to store values:

#### FB_manager.cs: (script that contains data)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;


public class FB_manager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static FB_manager _instance;

    public static FB_manager Instance
    {
        get {
            if(_instance == null){
                GameObject fbm = new GameObject("FBManager");
                fbm.AddComponent<FB_manager>();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn {get; set;}
    public string ProfileName {get; set;}
    public Sprite ProfilePic {get; set;}
    public string ProfileEmail {get; set;}

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        _instance = this;
    }

    public void InitFB(){
        if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK
            FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        } else {
            IsLoggedIn = FB.IsLoggedIn;
        }
    }

    private void InitCallback()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) {
            Debug.Log("FB is logged in");
            GetProfile();
            FB.ActivateApp();
        } else {
            Debug.Log("FB not logged in");
        }

         IsLoggedIn = FB.IsLoggedIn;

    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            // Pause the game - we will need to hide
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void GetProfile(){
        FB.API("/me?fields=first_name",HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUserName);
        FB.API("/me/picture?type=square&height=128&&widht=128",HttpMethod.GET,             DisplayProfilePic);
        FB.API("/me?fields=email",HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUserEmail);
    }

    void DisplayUserName(IResult result){

        if(result.Error == null){
            ProfileName = "" + result.ResultDictionary["first_name"];
        } else {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);
        }

    }

    void DisplayUserEmail(IResult result){

        if(result.Error == null){
            Debug.Log(result);
            ProfileEmail = "" + result.ResultDictionary["id"];
        } else {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);
        }

    }

    void DisplayProfilePic(IGraphResult result){

        if(result.Texture != null){
            ProfilePic = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2());
        } else {
            Debug.Log(result.Error);
        }

    }
}
```

#### FB_script.cs: (script that contains data)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class FB_script : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject DialogLoggedIn;
    public GameObject DialogLoggedOut;
    public GameObject logInStatusLabel;
    public GameObject Name;
    public GameObject ProfilePic;

    void Awake()
    {
        FB_manager.Instance.InitFB();
        HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    public void FBLogin() {
        var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email",     "user_friends", "publish_actions"};
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
    }

    private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
            Debug.Log("User logged in");
            FB_manager.Instance.IsLoggedIn = true;
            FB_manager.Instance.GetProfile();
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }
        } else{
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
        HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    void HandleMenu(bool isLoggedIn) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            DialogLoggedIn.SetActive(true);
            DialogLoggedOut.SetActive(false);
            logInStatusLabel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Logged in as: ";

            if(FB_manager.Instance.ProfileName!=null){
                Text userName = Name.GetComponent<Text>();
                userName.text = "" + FB_manager.Instance.ProfileName;
            } else {
                StartCoroutine("WaitForProfileName");
            }

            if(FB_manager.Instance.ProfilePic!=null){
                Image image = ProfilePic.GetComponent<Image>();
                image.sprite = FB_manager.Instance.ProfilePic;
            } else {
                StartCoroutine("WaitForProfilePic");
            }

            if(FB_manager.Instance.ProfileEmail!=null){
                Text userName = Name.GetComponent<Text>();
                userName.text = "" + FB_manager.Instance.ProfileEmail;
            } else {
              StartCoroutine("WaitForProfileEmail");
            }

        } else {
            DialogLoggedIn.SetActive(false);
            DialogLoggedOut.SetActive(true);
            logInStatusLabel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Not logged in";
        }
    }


    IEnumerator WaitForProfileName(){
        while(FB_manager.Instance.ProfileName==null){
            yield return null;
        }
        HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForProfilePic(){
        while(FB_manager.Instance.ProfilePic==null){
            yield return null;
        }
        HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForProfileEmail(){
        while(FB_manager.Instance.ProfileEmail==null){
            yield return null;
        }
        HandleMenu(FB.IsLoggedIn);
    } 
}
```

I can connect to the database within Unity so that it access the database in order to update the table. Giving only update privileges when connecting within unity. The **id** and **sc** can then be enclosed by a script (embedding php into the script) to update the table. Will users be able to change the **id** inside the script? When deploying the game will user be able to edit scripts?

Comment: When the user logs in, save the user ID in a session variable. Use that instead of a URL parameter.

Comment: If the script runs on the server, users can't modify it. If it runs on the client, they can change it and you can't trust the data they send. Anything that should be secured must be done on the server.

Comment: Can you share some of the php code you use to authenticate with Facebook api?

Comment: Thanks all for replying :) @JeffPuckettII Added the scripts that i'll be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logs in with Facebook credentials, then set their id in a session variable. Use the session variable in your sql query so that only the user can update their cards.